# как конвертировать видео vk в daxab или crazycloud

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, vk-streaming-api

Первоначальный источник `https://vk.com/video-71893149_636242344`

у меня есть эта функция, но не работает

потому что у видео есть ключ "extra". любая помощь

```
 function findServer(video){
   const crazycloud = ['13-2','14-2','15-2','16-2','17-2','20-2','13-1','14-1','15-1','16-1','17-1','20-1','13-3','16-3','17-3','20-3','13-4','16-4','13-5','13-6'];

  const daxab = ['11-1','11-2','11-3','11-4','12-1','12-4','12-5','19-1','19-2','21-1','21-2','25-1','25-2','27-1','27-2','29-1','36-1','36-2','38-1','38-2','38-3','43-1','45-1','46-1','47-1','48-1','49-1','49-2','49-3','49-4','49-5','49-6','49-7','50-1','51-1','52-1','53-1','54-1','55-1','56-1','57-1','58-1','59-1','60-1'];
  crazycloud.forEach(el=>{
    let server = '//psv' + el + '.crazycloud.ru/videos/';
    console.log(server + video );
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET',server + video, true);
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      return server + video
    }
  });
  daxab.forEach(el=>{
    let server = 'http://psv' + el + '.daxab.com/videos/';
    console.log(server + video );
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET',server + video, true);
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      return server + video
    }
  });
  return 'not found'
}
console.log( findServer('-71893149/636242344/720.mp4') );
```

фактическое видео - `https://psv20-3.crazycloud.ru/videos/-71893149/636242344/720.mp4?extra=iY2osxqXIhW8XJNARw0gRg`
или же `https://psv27-1.daxab.com/videos/-71893149/636242344/720.mp4?extra=iY2osxqXIhW8XJNARw0gRg`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Не работает, потому что `return server + video` - написано в цикле, результат никуда не возвращается. По ссылкам `https://psv20-3.crazycloud.ru/videos/-71893149/636242344/720.mp4?extra=iY2osxqXIhW8XJNARw0gRg` ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код. Но на момент публикации, видео не доступно и возвращает 404.

```js
async function findServer(video) {
  const crazycloud = ['13-2', '14-2', '15-2', '16-2', '17-2', '20-2', '13-1', '14-1', '15-1', '16-1', '17-1', '20-1', '13-3', '16-3', '17-3', '20-3', '13-4', '16-4', '13-5', '13-6'];

  const daxab = ['11-1', '11-2', '11-3', '11-4', '12-1', '12-4', '12-5', '19-1', '19-2', '21-1', '21-2', '25-1', '25-2', '27-1', '27-2', '29-1', '36-1', '36-2', '38-1', '38-2', '38-3', '43-1', '45-1', '46-1', '47-1', '48-1', '49-1', '49-2', '49-3', '49-4', '49-5', '49-6', '49-7', '50-1', '51-1', '52-1', '53-1', '54-1', '55-1', '56-1', '57-1', '58-1', '59-1', '60-1'];

  const getVideo = async(url) => {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(url);
      console.log(url, result);
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  for (let el of crazycloud) {
    let url = '//psv' + el + '.crazycloud.ru/videos/' + video;
    const res = await getVideo(url);
    if (res) {
      return res;
    }
  }
  for (let el of daxab) {
    let url = 'http://psv' + el + '.daxab.com/videos/' + video;
    const res = await getVideo(url);
    if (res) {
      return res;
    }
  }
  return 'not found';
}

(async function() {
  console.log(await findServer('-71893149/636242344/720.mp4'));
})();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ
Это проблема, как я могу получить точное время

Comment: Какое время вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Вы сказали: «Но на момент публикации видео недоступно и возвращает 404.»

Comment: @AnastazjaColbert ничего не понял. Ссылки, которые вы привели в вопросе https://psv20-3.crazycloud.ru/videos/-71893149/636242344/720.mp4?extra=iY2osxqXIhW8XJNARw0gRg или же https://psv27-1.daxab.com/videos/-71893149/636242344/720.mp4?extra=iY2osxqXIhW8XJNARw0gRg возвращаю 404 ошибку. При чем тут время?

Comment: Я не знаю, вы упомянули время, во всяком случае, почему он возвращает 404 ?